# How do you integrate SNMP with spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, snmp

I'm building a web app using spring mvc. I want to use SNMP protocole how to that?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use [snmp4j](https://www.snmp4j.org/).

> SNMP4J supports command generation (managers) as well as command responding (agents).

Here is a tutorial which seem a good starting point: [Create SNMP Client in JAVA Using SNMP4j](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/)

You can add it to your `pom.xml` with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I used this some time ago, could help: https://github.com/mastermark/log4j-snmp-trap-appender.